# Filemaker Pro popover showing a list with values to select from or a searchable dropdown

Tags: popover, filemaker

I'm a FM beginner and would like to know how I can show a searchable dropdown. When I create a product, I need to select a supplier from a large list. I would like to tyoe some characters, from where I find a value in the dropdown. As far as I see now, that isn't possible and the only way to do this is through a popover.

But my question is then, how to show a full table in the popover, from which I can select a value, which is filled in my form.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to tyoe some characters, from where I find a value in the dropdown. As far as I see now, that isn't possible and the only way to do this is through a popover.

Actually, it's the other way around: with a drop-down list you get the option to **Auto-complete using value list**, which is unavailable with a pop-up menu.

> how to show a full table in the popover, from which I can select a value,

You cannot show a full table in a popover. You can show a *portal* in a popover, and make it show all records in a table by using the `x` operator when defining the relationship.

Or - preferably, IMHO - use a [card window](https://help.claris.com/en/pro-help/index.html#page/FMP_Help/window-styles.html) to show all the records you want to select from; this could be the full table or a reduced set as the result of a find.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting products or other related records using popovers always feels slow when you try to search/filter the list of records, with the introduction of card windows doing such searches/selects became a lot faster and easier to implement, if you have 2 different layouts that need to search the same list of records you can use the same card window for both, that was also a nice thing.